# Gitlab Runners on K8s multiple runner tags same runner controller

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to figure out how to have different "classes" of runners example would be small, medium and large. This is so I can optimize cost for the runners and also speed up deployment times by having the small ones ready and the large ones spin up as needed.

I currently have a single class of large runners using the below config in my values file for the gitlab runner helm chart. How can I change it to add a different "class" of runner?

```
runners:
  image: "docker:20.10.16"
  tags: "large"
  privileged: true
  disable_cache: false 
  cache_dir: "cache"
  namespace: gitlab
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      output_limit = 24576
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        cpu_limit = "12"
        cpu_request = "8"
        memory_limit = "48Gi"
        memory_request = "32Gi"
```